# Regarding spoiler text

Tags: discussion, spoilers

I think spoilers should be used only when asked for by the OP, etc and not too freely.

1. I usually take a  printout of answers that I find useful, or too dense. Printouts have spoilers as blank text ***Edit***: Aryabhata has suggested [stackprinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/) app which works
2. It does not show underlying text on mobile touch based devices (ipad, etc) so to read such answers while commuting, I have to click on edit, look at the source, and exit without saving any edits.

(Spoilers are not proliferate in the main site yet, but I asked this question as I noticed a problem and wouldn't want it to become a bother later.)

Comment: Perhaps we convert this to a feature request: Have a print stylesheet which shows the spoilers...

Comment: @Aryabhata As you wish. Add to the request something like onMouseover capability for ipad (i.e it should be visible for tablets\iphones as well)

Comment: Moreover, it is probably not exactly the most convenient thing from the accessibitity point of view.

Comment: btw, for printing, apparently this is good: http://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite

Comment: I tested a spoiler answer to be printed using the stackprint app: http://www.stackprinter.com/ and it seems to show the spoilers. So we atleast have a workaround...

Comment: I agree with @Mariano and would go a step further and say that one should simply avoid that "feature". It makes little sense and makes a posts rather unreadable. For the 10K+ users, [here's a recent example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47547/is-there-a-continuous-bijection-from-mathbbr-to-mathbbr2/47567#47567) of what I mean (fortunately GEdgar had the patience and spotted a mistake).

Comment: My understanding (not having an ipad myself) is that iPads can deal with onMouseover events. You need to do a quick light tap to activate the mouseover. (In the case that a clickable link has mouseovers, a second tap will actually click the link.)

Comment: It is also recommended that you print SE pages using StackPrinter. There are often formatting difficulties on questions with many answers if you just print directly.

Comment: @willie the onmouseover does not work for spoilers (and is a terrribly inconvenient thing in itself, but that's a different story) which is why I posted the question

Comment: @Aryabhatt thanks.

Comment: @Aryabhata: Your new handle seems to be a bit difficult to spell correctly. I like it much more than the other one, especially after you decided to drop that second t :)

Comment: @THeo: Yeah :-) There are acceptable variations and as long as people get the first 3 or 4 letters correctly (which seems to be the case with all the variations I have seen), I do get notified.

Comment: @Ary: Not quite, @Aryabhatta won't work `:-)`

Comment: @Hendrik: I was notified :-)

Comment: @Aryabhatta: Now you won't `:-)`

Comment: @Hendrik: You are right! This is strange... It is supposed to work. I guess they changed something (or I had it wrong all this time).

Comment: @Aryab: No, they didn't change anything. All of these work: @Ary, @Arya, @Aryab, @Aryabh and so on. It suffices to type at least 3 characters, but everything you type has to be an exact match. And this is important if there are, e.g., Cornelius and Cornelia participating in a comment thread.

Comment: @Hendrik: I see. Thanks! (and apologies to kuch nahin for the multiple pings).

Comment: @Arya Not a problem. But I guess I might have to give some respect to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryabhata#Name) and stop using the (phonetically correct, with no anglical and redundant "a" suffixed) spelling @aryabhatt

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good suggestion; we'll make sure the spoiler block is made visible in the print stylesheet.

There is always [Stack Printer](http://www.stackprinter.com/) as indicated above, too.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would you guys be rolling out tablet version of the site sometime in the future? Maybe an android/iOS app?

Comment: +1 for StackPrinter :P

Answer (score 9):

I have fixed this on our dev server. Spoiler text will show up as black when printed. The change should be in our next production deployment(later tonight or tomorrow).